# C++ 2D vector declaration and element access from debugger

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I'm currently trying to create a dimensional vector of doubles of 256*256. I read the documentation and I think I'm declaring it well.

```
int rows1 = 256;
int cols1 = 256;

vector<vector<double>> LBP1(rows1, vector<double>(cols1));
```

The problem is that when i go debugging it has only 256 of size.

And when i access their elements in a cycle like:

```
LBP1[i][j]
```

The debug gives me: "no operator "[]" matches these operands". I already solved this problem with vector._Myfunction for one-dimensional cases but here I’m struggling a little bit with the solution.

If someone could explain me why this happens i would be very thankful.

Comment: It works here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c0d04c3ae491fe1

Comment: What do you mean "when i go debugging it has only 256 of size"? How are you testing this? Also, `LBP1[i][j] ` is the correct way to access an item within a vector of vectors so without seeing your loop we will not be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the first vector will be 256, it contains 256 other vectors all of size 256.

Your syntax for `LDB1[i][j]` is correct. Most likely your debugger is failing to handle it correctly. Check whether it works in code and that will confirm.

You can try using the `at` method in your debugger instead.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/

Comment: @TiagoFreitas Not sure why it would happen, see edited answer for a potential work around.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration is correct. `LBP1.size()==256` because this is the number of elements in the outer vector. Your debugger probably has a problem displaying overloaded operator[] (this is a separate large topic).

Comment: Thanks for the response! That makes sense. So is there a way i could visit the LBP1 values while debugging to make sure everything is ok?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not declaring 2-dimensional vector. You are declaring a vector of vectors, and it is usually not very syntaxically welcome.

If you need to perform a matrix algebra on your 2D structure, you should really use already available matrix clasess. And if you simply need a structure to represent 2-D layout (a 2D coordinate map, for instance) it is much better to use a single vector and access it in a quasi-2D style, like following:

```
std::vector<int> vec(n_columns * n_rows);

int i = vec[x + y * n_rows];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response,

You're correct. I was declaring a vector of vector. Thanks for the tip !